# How to set shell variable to result of evaluation in OS/X

Tags: macos, bash

In Linux Bash I can do the following:

```
$ export CP=$(cat classpath.txt)
```

If we do "cat classpath" we see a very long output (that's why I am not reproducing here).

However in OS/X the same command results in CP is empty.  What is the OS/X equivalent of that command?

```
2:21:59/mllib $ls -l classpath
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  13162 Oct 28 12:19 classpath
12:26:46/mllib $export CP=$(cat classpath)
12:26:54/mllib $echo $CP

12:26:59/mllib $export CP=`cat classpath`
12:27:03/mllib $echo $CP
```

Comment: Can we see that `cat classpath` returns something if you don't try to assign it?

Comment: You don't need `export` on those lines unless you want the variables made available to programs the shell runs. And both of those examples should work... assuming the `classpath` file has any contents.

Comment: @ErlVolton   Please note in the OP that i do ls -l classpath and it is v large (13K) . I suspect the size may have something to do with the problem but am still investigating.

Comment: It's also possible that with sufficiently funny line endings (`\r` only perhaps) and lots of spaces on the last line, the variable may be getting set accurately but simply not appearing on-screen. Try `echo $CP | xxd` (or `hexdump`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always want to quote parameter expansions. In this case,

```
CP=$(cat classpath)
```

resulted in the value of `CP` containing a `*`. Since you had `shopt -s nullglob`, which causes a non-matching shell pattern to expand to the empty string rather than being treated literally, the command

```
echo $CP
```

produce the empty string, because the value of `CP` underwent pathname expansion, but did not match any files. If you had quoted it:

```
echo "$CP"
```

it would have output the path, since the quoted expansion would *not* undergo pathname expansion.

---

Alternatively, turning off `nullglob` with

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

causes an unmatched pattern to be treated literally, so that `echo $CP` would produce the unmatched pattern as output. I wouldn't consider this a solution, though, since it only "works" when the pattern doesn't match anything. It's better to properly quote your parameter expansions.

Comment: **You always want to quote parameter expansions** It should be printed in banner size and be placed at every shell programmer's desk :) +1

Comment: Or at the very least, on the question submission page :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that inside the large classpath file there was ONE entry with an asterisk:

```
/shared/libs/*
```

By Removing that asterisk entry then the evaluation works fine.

The next step is to understand how to escape the asterisk so the full/correct classpath may be used.

**UPDATE** From a comment bye @chepner, i tried removing the shopt -s nullglob. That was the culprit!

```
12:54:38/mllib $shopt -u nullglob
12:54:45/mllib $vi classpath
12:54:53/mllib $export CP="$(cat classpath)"
12:55:00/mllib $echo $CP
/shared/scala/lib/*:/shared/mllib/mllib/target/scala-2.10/classes:
```

**Another update**  The *output* of the $CP needs to be quoted. I had put quotes on the assignmnt side but not the usage.

e.g.  echo "$CP" does work.

Comment: `/shared/libs/*` can't make it go blank, there might be some funny characters in this file that you can see using `xxd` or `cat -vte`

Comment: You probably don't want to escape it; rather you want to quote your parameter expansions: `echo "$CP"`. (That said, I don't understand how `echo $CP` produces no output, unless you have `shopt -s nullglob` and there are no files that match that pattern.)

Comment: @anubhava  I removed that one character and it made the difference. Repeatably.

Comment: @chepner I DO have shopt -s nullglob.  I will try w/o it to see how makes difference

Comment: With `shopt -s nullglob` you must use quotes in `echo "$CP"`

Comment: @anubhava  The quotes did not fix it. Only after shopt -u nullgob (  as shown in the update to my answer) fixed it.

Comment: @chepner. If you want points make your shopt info a formal answer and I will award.

Comment: You always want to quote parameter expansions, precisely because of situations like this. Unquoted, the value of `CP` undergoes pathname generation after `$CP` is expanded.

Comment: @chepner  the double quotes did not help. The shopt -u did the trick - please make that portion an answer

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible script to prove that. I have OSX 10.9.5 with BASH 4.2.45 and with `shopt -s nullglob` it works fine when quoted.

Comment: @javadba: If you want you can create a new question showing how quotes don't work for you in this case.

Comment: @anubhava Oh I see - i missed the quotes on printing the variable echo "$CP". I had been putting them on the assignment step.

Comment: That's why I and @chepner even typed the `echo` command in our comments :)

Comment: @anubhava  OK you win. Although I am working on my attention to details it will never be my strong suit.