# Why does $(date +%N) sometimes return "N" rather than the current timestamp in nanoseconds?

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh

I the following function in my .zshrc file (on OS X, using the coreutils date implementation) :

```
# Display timestamped debugging messages when ZSHDBG is enabled.
function zshdbg () {
  if [[ $ZSHDBG -eq 1 ]]; then
    purple="\x1b[35;01m"
    reset="\x1b[39;49;00m"
    now=$(date '+%F %T')
    nanoseconds=$(date +%N)

    # For some reason on OSX, %N is sometimes returned as "N" rather than the
    # current nanosecond timestamp. This is a nasty hack for providing a
    # default value in those unfortunate cases.
    # if [[ "$nanoseconds" -eq 'N' ]]; then
    #   nanoseconds='000000000'
    # fi

    echo "$purple$now [$nanoseconds] $1$reset"
  fi
}
```

For some reason, the nanoseconds are sometimes returned as "N":

```
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Antigen installation detected.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Last update on . Current date 2014-10-28 21:45:42. It's been  days since the last update.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Loading antigen.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Setting oh-my-zsh as the default antigen plugin repository.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Enabling OS X specific plugins.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Loading plugin zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Loading theme jonathan.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Applying the antigen configuration.
2014-10-28 21:45:42 [N] Setting default exports.
2014-10-28 21:45:43 [N] OS X detected, executing OS specific configuration.
2014-10-28 21:45:43 [N] Homebrew detected. Configuring paths.
2014-10-28 21:45:43 [084632000] Finished loading .zshrc.
```

This is using the coreutils date command:

```
which date
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date
```

However, if I explicitly call /bin/date, I still get similar behavior:

```
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Antigen installation detected.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Last update on . Current date 2014-10-28 21:50:47. It's been  days since the last update.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Loading antigen.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Setting oh-my-zsh as the default antigen plugin repository.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Enabling OS X specific plugins.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Loading plugin zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Loading theme jonathan.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Applying the antigen configuration.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Setting default exports.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] OS X detected, executing OS specific configuration.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Homebrew detected. Configuring paths.
2014-10-28 21:50:47 [N] Finished loading .zshrc.
```

I've been digging through the documentation for date, zsh, and homebrew's coreutils, but not finding anything relevant. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `date` supplied with OS X does not support `+N`, so `/bin/date +N` simply prints "N". I suspect your PATH isn't consistent, specifically that `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` is not (always) listed before `/bin`. Try this:

```
# Display timestamped debugging messages when ZSHDBG is enabled.
function zshdbg () {
  if [[ $ZSHDBG -eq 1 ]]; then
    purple="\x1b[35;01m"
    reset="\x1b[39;49;00m"
    now=$(date '+%F %T')
    nanoseconds=$(/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date +%N)

    echo "$purple$now [$nanoseconds] $1$reset"
  fi
}
```

If that fixes it, you should try to track down what's messing with PATH, because this probably isn't the only effect...

Comment: I think that it was a combination of the paths and the formatting - both issues I actually fixed at the same time, but didn't realize the other was also a culprit. When I was doing the original testing, I was checking if we were on OSX, then prepending the coreutils *after* oh-my-zsh was loaded by antigen - however that function was being called prior to the point in my zsh configuration where the coreutils/homebrew paths were prefixed. That chunk of code was moved to the beginning of my .zshenv file, so that the paths are correct in subshells. Seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: @nfarrar Actually, I'd put the formatting back the way it was before -- with very few exceptions, you should keep variable references between double-quotes to prevent unexpected word-splitting and wildcard expansion. In this case it's probably safe, but take a look at [this recent question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616849/how-to-set-shell-variable-to-result-of-evaluation-in-os-x) for an example of unexpected consequences from an unquoted variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.3.12 (2011), `zsh` has the `epochtime` array and `EPOCHREALTIME` variable in the `zsh/datetime` module, so you don't need to call an external `date` command (which would take several thousands of nanoseconds to run).

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime "%F %T [$epochtime[2]]" $epochtime[1]
2014-10-31 16:17:13 [698637482]
```

Comment: Yes, but if you are aiming for portability in scripts, that isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @AdamC, that will work in a zsh script regardless of what system it's on, there's nothing macos specific in that. The great majority of currently maintained systems will ship or make available in a package a version of zsh greater than 4.3.12 as it's rare for a version of an OS to be supported for over 10 years.

Comment: I believe you, but there are a whole bunch of reasons you may not want to ship scripts limited to running in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

After monkeying around a little bit more, I found that the following works:

```
function zshdbg () {
  if [[ $ZSHDBG -eq 1 ]]; then
    purple="\x1b[35;01m"
    reset="\x1b[39;49;00m"
    now=$(date '+%F %T')
    nanoseconds=$(date +%N)

    echo $purple$now" ["$nanoseconds"] "$1$reset
  fi
}
```

It generates the output:

```
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [647272000] Antigen installation detected.
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [663708000] Last update on 1414545789. Current date 1414556852. It's been  days since the last update.
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [669752000] Loading antigen.
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [681586000] Setting oh-my-zsh as the default antigen plugin repository.
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [807303000] Enabling OS X specific plugins.
2014-10-28 22:27:32 [944470000] Loading plugin zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.
2014-10-28 22:27:33 [034537000] Loading theme jonathan.
2014-10-28 22:27:33 [125400000] Applying the antigen configuration.
2014-10-28 22:27:33 [171657000] Setting default exports.
2014-10-28 22:27:33 [303480000] Finished loading .zshrc.
```

With the nanoseconds being generated correctly in all cases. Not sure exactly what was going on. It may have been related to the way the brackets were formatted around the $nanoseconds variable substitution.